# How can I remove an entry in global configuration with git config?

Tags: git

I ran a global configuration command in **git** to exclude certain files using a `.gitignore_global` file:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Is there a way to undo the creation of this setting globally?

Comment: Just edit the file with `git config --global --edit`

Answer (score 1119, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "undo" the change.  You can remove the `core.excludesfile` setting like this:

```
git config --global --unset core.excludesfile
```

And of course you can simply edit the config file:

```
git config --global --edit
```

...and then remove the setting by hand.

Comment: Just if you have the same key repeated (because you did an --add instead of --edit), this command will not work but you can do `git config --replace-all core.excludesfile "your_value"`

Comment: I wanted to change this back to "input" but found the existing setting under `system` scope so I used `git config --system --edit` to change my entry.

Comment: "You can tell Git to convert CRLF to LF on commit but not the other way around by setting core.autocrlf to input:"       From: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Comment: For Windows, you can edit the file at C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.gitconfig

Comment: In my case, this does not work for some filter settings; I was able to find the file by `git config -l --show-origin` and I went to the file to edit its content.

Comment: @larsks I am afraid the second one will work only if `core.editor` is correct :-)

Answer (score 131):

You can use the `--unset` flag of `git config` to do this like so:

```
git config --global --unset user.name
git config --global --unset user.email
```

If you have more variables for one config you can use:

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name
```

Answer (score 46):

Open config file to edit :

```
git config --global --edit
```

Press <kbd>Insert</kbd> and remove the setting

and finally type `:wq` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.

Comment: This is valid, only if you are in linux and you  open it with `vim`

Comment: @yeaaaahhhh..hamfhamf no you can open it in the terminal, this is not a vim exclusive thing

Comment: @0xdeadbeef   `:wq` and  `Enter` is vim exclusive

Comment: I'm talking about `git config --global --edit`

Answer (score 32):

Try this from the command line to change the git config details.

```bash
git config --global --replace-all user.name "Your New Name"

git config --global --replace-all user.email "Your new email"
```

Answer (score 28):

You can check all the config settings using

```
git config --global --list
```

You can remove the setting for example username

```
git config --global --unset user.name
```

You can edit the configuration or remove the config setting manually by hand using:

```
git config --global --edit
```

Answer (score 24):

In order to complement the larsk anwser, is possible remove an entry line while editing with vim using the dd command:

```
git config --global --edit
```

then:

- Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to go to normal mode.
- Place the cursor on the line you want to delete.
- Type `dd` and hit Enter to remove the line.

when you finish, type `ESQ` and `:wq`

Answer (score 20):

Try these commands to remove all users' usernames and emails.

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name
git config --global --unset-all user.email
```

Answer (score 13):

This would unset global credential helper.

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Answer (score 10):

If someone just wanna delete the `user` object entirely, then he should use:

```
git config --global --remove-section user
```

This is useful when a user accidentally adds more properties that are not required just like `user.password` etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can edit the `~/.gitconfig` file in your home folder. This is where all `--global` settings are saved.

Answer (score 5):

git config information will stored in `~/.gitconfig` in unix platform.

In Windows it will be stored in `C:/users/<NAME>/.gitconfig.`

You can edit it manually by opening this files and deleting the fields which you are interested.