# How can I delete git user property?

Tags: git, git-config

I accidentally typed the following wrong git command.

```
git config --global user.mail example@example.com
```

and now I see an extra property when I type `git config--list`:

```
user.mail = "example@example.com"
```

How can i get rid of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove an entry in global configuration with git config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868447/how-can-i-remove-an-entry-in-global-configuration-with-git-config)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git config --global --unset user.mail`

From the man page

```
   --unset
       Remove the line matching the key from config file.
```