# Delete remote repo URL which is not on .git/config?

Tags: git, github

Recently I made new  project and with new repository on github.

But when I push to the new repository, it also tries to push to old repository which I never connected with the new project, Like this:

[image]

The old repo is in the same Github account with new repo, but it is connected to another project of mine (hence fail to push)

When I check my remote on my new project, it shows these

[image]

I tried to delete & change the url with set-url, or delete ... But the old url is still there

My .git/config file is

[image]

it doesn't have old repo url.

Pushing to new project is actually working well, but everytime I push to new one it always tries to push to old one & fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happened to my Xcode project, so after digging in again I found out my own answer.
The problem was on the global file.

[How can i delete git user property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379184/how-can-i-delete-git-user-property)
This answer helped me.

```
git config --global --unset remote.origin.url OLD.REPO.URL
```

This finally solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The output from `git remove -v` shows `origin` set to push to both the old and new repositories.  Assuming you don't want this, you can try removing `origin` completely, then adding it back again with the correct settings:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

and then

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I tried this, but this didn't work. `git remote rm origin` removed my new repo url only, so when I put `git remote set-url origin (new repo)` there were still two urls remain. Seemed like the old repo url wasn't affected by all these `git remote` commands.

Comment: `git remote add origin` doesn't work, saying `fatal: remote origin already exists.` `git remote rm origin` doesn't remove my old repo url.

Comment: Can you try `git remote remove origin`?  What version of Git are you using?

Comment: It's the same command, right? At least for me. I tried it before but result was the same. Version is git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81).

Comment: After running `git remote rm origin` try running `git remote -v` ... what do you now see?

Comment: It removes my new repo url, shows `old repo (fetch)` `old repo (push)`.

Comment: My answer should have worked.  Are you certain that the old remote is really called `origin`?  Could there be any whitespace in the name?

Comment: I know it should have worked... I searched for everything but none of them worked. The second image I posted shows that the old remote name is origin, but I haven't thought about whitespace. Is there anyway to check that?

Comment: But again I think the name of old repo is also origin, because 'git remote add origin doesn't work, saying fatal: remote origin already exists.'

Answer (score 0):

Reading from your image `error` and `hint`.
you can follow this way

1. create a local branch
2. checkout in local branch
3. change your files or add files what ever want
4. commit there
5. than push it to master branch

you can do 1 and 2 by 
`git checkout - b local_branch`
and then `commit` and `push` command.

Comment: Pushing to the old repository is not what I want. Git with this new project shouldn't be pushed to that old repo.