# what is the purpose of git remote origin variable in .gitconfig file

Tags: git

I have this below in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[remote "origin"]
   url = https://github.com/eldur/jwbf
```

Now when I do:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/skicka.git
```

git clone the `https://github.com/eldur/jwbf` project to `skicka` folder. Is it normal?

Comment: Back up. What folder structure are we talking about here? You shouldn't be cloning a git repo inside another one unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I didn't know that there's `.gitconfig` file in my folder. I just tried to clone the second project and got the other project. I didn't know whare problem cam from. I have tried some git command a week ago but I didn't know that I have configured the remote.

Comment: It's very unusual to have a remote configured in `.gitconfig`, your user's global configuration file. Only things that should apply to *all* of your repositories belong in there. That could be causing a problem.

Comment: I hate to even give you advice here because it's so unclear from what information you have provided what your folder structure is or if this will break something, but it sounds like you should remove that line from your `.gitconfig`.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that's what I have done. So what's the purpose to set a remote in your global `.gitconfig` ?

Comment: There is no purpose to doing that. It should not be done for any reason I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

First, [remove any `remote` entry from your global config file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11868447/6309)

```
git config --global --unset-all remote.origin
```

Then clone your repo as usual (your second clone won't get the first repo!), and check your *local* config:

```
cd /path/to/local/second/cloned/repo
git config --local
```

You should see a remote.origin value which will match the repo you just cloned.

Comment: You don't answer my question. I asked to know why it is possible to set remote globally to end up not able doing a clone by specifying an url.

Comment: @user230137 with `git config --global`. Why or how you did a git config --global, I don't know. So to answer your question "Is it normal?": no, it is not, and here is how to fix it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I did by mistake when following some tutorial. It took me some time to figure out the problem so I was curious to know why this feature is included in git.

Comment: @user230137 sure: the global config (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115116/6309) is usually for properties you want to apply to *all* repos (like `user.name` and `user.email`)