# Removing winmerge from git

Tags: windows, git

I have a Windows 7 computer at work that someone else used before I joined the company. They have git setup with winmerge. While it may be a good idea, I want to remove it and return to a basic "default" git installation.

I tried uninstalling git and gitextensions (which I found on the computer) and after the restart I reinstalled git. I still see the same winmerge options when I do git config --list.

Here is a screenshot of what it is telling me. How would I restore this computer to a default install without winmerge? Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot from git config --list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/braSb.jpg)

Or here is the code (not that "$REMOTE" is from the previous line)

```
core.editor="C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe"        fileeditor
merge.tool=DiffMerge
diff.guitool=winmerge
credential.helper=!\"C:/Program Files     (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\"
difftool.winmerge.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/winmergeu.exe
difftool.winmerge.cmd="C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/winmergeu.exe" -e -u     "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
mergetool.DiffMerge.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/winmergeu.exe`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove an entry in global configuration with git config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868447/how-can-i-remove-an-entry-in-global-configuration-with-git-config)

Comment: While the information there is relevant and helpful, I wanted to know about reverting to default settings. Based on those links, I should be able to update these settings. The question is what should be updated and how (i.e. where should core.editor link to ??"

Comment: A default installation doesn't include a global git config file, simply delete the file

Comment: Perfect, thank you Andrew C.

Answer (score 0):

Like @AndrewC said in the comments, you can delete the `.gitconfig` file found in your user profile (`C:\Users\User\.gitconfig`).

Alternatively, you can do `git config --global --edit` and manually delete the lines from the file opened.