# How to delete a git configuration?

Tags: git

Basically, I entered:

```
git config --global use.name "My name"
```

Notice I wrote "use.name" instead of "user.name." But now that field is there, so I was wondering how to delete it.

Comment: Rewrite the command to replace the incorrect config.

Comment: user.name is indeed there, but I was hoping to remove use.name. Or am I misunderstanding? Thanks.

Comment: then edit your ~/.gitconfig to delete use section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove an entry in global configuration with git config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868447/how-can-i-remove-an-entry-in-global-configuration-with-git-config)

Answer (score 24):

You can remove it by using the `--unset` option of git config:

```
git config --global --unset use.name
```

See the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

```
git config --global --unset use.name
```

or you can edit config by --edit

```
git config --global --edit
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the section by

```
git config --global --remove-section use
```

and then

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

The config is stored in home directory.
Try editing `~/.gitconfig`

You will see something like:

```
[use]
        name = My name
```

You can change it to

```
[user]
        name = My name
```

Or you can execute the same command with correction.

Comment: Thanks, assuming you mean for me to open gitconfig in text edit, I don't see my "[use]" category there. Only "[user]." Perhaps there is a command I can use to get rid of [use]?

Comment: @bin1six: as mentioned by other users, you can unset it

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple git accounts on my machine and only thing that worked was

```
git config --local --unset credential.helper
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --system --unset credential.helper

git config --local --unset user.name
git config --global --unset user.name
git config --system --unset user.name

git config --local --unset user.email
git config --global --unset user.email
git config --system --unset user.email
```

Answer (score -2):

Git command to unset user name in global git config:

```
git config --global --unset user.name "name"
```

Comment: This merely seems to restate earlier answers, with a typo.