# bad numeric config value 'tru' for 'core.longpaths': invalid unit

Tags: git, sourcetree

I can't launch repositories on sourcetree.

I get:

```
bad numeric config value 'tru' for 'core.longpaths': invalid unit
```

It's happened after I tried to clone a project with a long file name.
And then i tried to enable the "`core.longpaths`".

How to fix it please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply edit your global git config named `.gitconfig` in your `$HOME` (or `%USERPROFILE%` on Windows)

You need to replace `tru` with `true` or [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868676/6309) `core.longpaths` altogether from your global settings.

In command line, [you can also type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26111092/6309):

```
git config --global unset core.longpaths
cd /path/to/my/repo
git config core.longpaths true
```

Checks your SourceTree settings though: make sure it is using the System’s Git and not the embedded one.

---

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), documentation on various Boolean `GIT_*` environment variables have been clarified regarding boolean values:

See [commit 819fb68](https://github.com/git/git/commit/819fb682225e096096b05c4a3aff16ebcabfcfd4), [commit b724df6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b724df6b559d895b035cafa6f7e55216f581f7c1), [commit fd01795](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd01795beb1bda7aa738b443bcb01cc9df70059a), [commit 80f0b3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80f0b3f397d6467cb6f6fc9456b867aaffdc9b8c), [commit 29491ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29491ca5fd8dcc4d60b985548c133756590b4b8a) (15 Sep 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a1fdfb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1fdfb09754cc477cd5134b064b0f0598ffb8713), 10 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`environ`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80f0b3f397d6467cb6f6fc9456b867aaffdc9b8c): explain Boolean environment variables

> Many environment variables use the `git_env_bool()` API to parse their values, and allow the usual "`true/yes/on` are true, `false/no/off` are false.
> In addition non-zero numbers are true and zero is false.
> An empty string is also false." set of values.
>
> Mark them as such, and consistently say "`true`" or "`false`", instead of random mixes of '`1`', '`0`', '`yes`', '`true`', etc.
> in their description.

Comment: I would first set it as a local config before trying to apply that to *all* repo through a global or system setting

Comment: Thank's i just change the git setting to "System git"

Comment: @Anna Well done. That way, SourceTree  and command-line both are using the same settings. Easier that way.