# How to undo the git command to change the diff checker

Tags: git, diff

I'm not able to undo some changes using `git` command. I'm using **Git Bash** for windows and unfortunately, while following a tuto to change my `git difftool` , I accidentally wrote this command :

```
$ git config --global diff.external git-meld
```

Now, if run the classic diff checker command, I got this error :

```
$ git diff
```

> error: cannot spawn meld.exe: No such file or directory
>
> fatal: external diff died, stopping at myJavaFile.java

Right now, I want to undo my first command in order to use native `git diff` again.

Any help ?

Comment: May be the following question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868447/how-can-i-remove-an-entry-in-global-configuration-with-git-config

Comment: Not yet. Isn't git revert only for commits (I don't want to undo my last commit) ?

Comment: Thanks @Susa, using your above link, I used `$ git config --global --unset diff.external` to undo my change and it worked !! :-)

Comment: You are right, git revert is just for commits that why i had to edit my comment. Good that your problem was solved! :-)