# How do I remove duplicate Git config values that contradict each other?

Tags: windows, git

I tried to remove the values (to reset them) but they won't go away. Plus they contradict each other.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\app>git config --unset-all core.autocrlf

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\app>git config --unset-all core.editor

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\app>git config --unset-all core.edit

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\app>git config -l | grep autocrlf
core.autocrlf=true
core.autocrlf=false

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\app>git config -l | grep notepad
core.editor=/C/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
core.edit=C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe
```

I tried to edit the values with `git config -e` (but first I had to figure out how to specify the path correctly), and it didn't list either of those config keys.

git version 2.16.3.windows.1

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868447/how-can-i-remove-an-entry-in-global-configuration-with-git-config/11868676#11868676

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `git config -l --show-origin` to see where from the settings come. Most probably from the global `~/.gitconfig` so remove them with

```
git config --global --unset-all core.autocrlf
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/ddg#2115116

And I used `git config --list --show-origin` then edited the files manually (from an elevated Notepad++). I had

```
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true
file:C:/Users/Chloe/.gitconfig  core.autocrlf=false
file:C:/Users/Chloe/.gitconfig  core.editor=/C/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
file:C:/Users/Chloe/.gitconfig  core.edit=C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe
```

Overall it was looking in 4 places: `C:\ProgramData\Git\config`, `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig`, `C:/Users/Chloe/.gitconfig`, `.git/config`.